# ASp.Net GridView Loading

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pageload

**I have a gridview in asp.net and I need to Bind this Gridview after the Page Load Completes.**

I mean that , the Gridview loading function take around 30-40 seconds to fetch the data from DB

In this case I want to load the page without any wait for the user, after the page completed the load, bind the gridview ( Like Google / Facebook online users area loading)

Thanks.

Comment: That's a task that might have several solutions, depending on taste and experience. What have you tried so far?

Comment: you will have to use Ajax, is it good for you?